# Force evaluation of all lazy function arguments

Tags: r

This is my function:

```
f <- function(a, b, ...){
  c(as.list(environment()), list(...))
}
```

If I call `f(a = 2)` no error will be raised, although `b` is missing. I would like to get an error in this case:

`Error in f(a = 2) : argument "b" is missing, with no default`

What piece of ***dynamic*** and efficient code I must add such that this error be raised? I was thinking something in line of the following: `force(as.symbol(names(formals())))`.

*Note:* In case you wonder why I need this kind of function: It is a way to standardize the kinds of lists. Such a list must have `a` and `b`, and possibly other keys. I could play with objects too...

*Solutions:* See Carl's answer or comments below.

```
f <- function(a, b, ...){
  sapply(ls(environment()), get, envir = environment(), inherits = FALSE)
  c(as.list(environment()), list(...))
}
```

Or

```
f <- function(a, b, ...){
  stopifnot(all(setdiff(names(formals()), '...') %in% names(as.list(match.call()[-1]))))
  c(as.list(environment()), list(...))
}
```

Comment: `x = c(as.list(match.call(f)[-1]), list(...)); if (!all(setdiff(names(formals(f)), "...") %in% names(x))) stop("Nah.")` seems to work, but I don't know if that's efficient or does what you're after.

Comment: @Frank Interesting perspective. The kind of error is not so important, as long as there is one. I am looking how to make it more "elegant"...

Comment: @Frank `stopifnot(all(setdiff(names(formals()), '...') %in% names(as.list(match.call()[-1]))))` is the most concise I can come up with. Not elegant, but does the job. You can post it as an answer. If no-one comes up with a better one-liner, then I'll accept yours.

Comment: I don't know these functions well enough to post, but feel free to post yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea... first check for all arguments that exist in the any function anonymously... meaning regardless of the functions, get the arguments into a list with no preset requirements:

```
#' A function to grab all arguments of any calling environment.. ie.. a function
#' 
#' 
#' \code{grab.args}
#' 
grab.args <- function() {
  envir <- parent.frame()
  func <- sys.function(-1)
  call <- sys.call(-1)
  dots <- match.call(func, call, expand.dots=FALSE)$...
  c(as.list(envir), dots)
}
```

Then, in whatever function you use it for.. store the initial arguments on a list `does_have`, then find all the arguments that are pre-defined in the environment with `should_have`, loop through the list to match names and find if any are missing values... if any are... create the error with the names that are missing, if not... do your thing...

```
#' As an example
#' 
f <- function(a, b, ...){
  does_have <- grab.args()
  should_have <- ls(envir = environment())
  check_all <- sapply(should_have, function(i){
    !nchar(does_have[[i]])
  })
  if(any(mapply(isTRUE, check_all))){
    need_these <- paste(names(which(mapply(isTRUE,check_all))), collapse = " and ")
    cat(sprintf('Values needed for %s', need_these))
  }else {
    does_have
  }

}
```

Outputs for cause....

```
> f(mine = "yours", a = 3)
Values needed for b
> f(b = 12)
Values needed for a
> f(hey = "you")
Values needed for a and b
```

#### Edit to throw an actual error...

```
f <- function(a,b,...){
    Filter(missing, sapply(ls(environment()), get, environment()))
}


> f(a = 2, wtf = "lol")
 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "b" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: ?missing is probably what you're after

Comment: Indeed. But it is not vectorized. So I can not do simply `missing(names(formals()))`. And all my other tryouts failed...

Comment: "something as simple"... maybe I'm misunderstanding your question? It sounded to me like you want to anonymously verify parameters in ANY function... and if it's a  "named" argument, and it's missing...see edit?

Comment: That is a smart solution. I don't understand why you need to `Filter` with missing. `sapply(ls(environment()), get, envir = environment(), inherits = FALSE)` is enough as a check. Much less code compared to your first answer for the same thing, no? Or am I missing something? Too bad `mget(ls(environment())` doesn't produce an error.

Comment: have you considered just using `tryCatch`.. and if the result is empty generate the error? My code is used universally in a bunch of my work so while it looks like a lot.. it's a shortcut overall in my use cases